# Creating a calculated column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table `XYZ` with 3 columns:

```
Environment Servers Databases
Dev         5        10
PROD        25       100
Test        9        10
TOTAL       39       120
```

I want to add another two columns to the table called `SERVER MAINTENANCE` and `DATABASE MAINTENANCE` based on the values of `TOTAL SERVERS` and `TOTAL DATABASES` (maybe a calculated column to the table, so that whenever the data is added to the table the column should have the automatically calculated value) 
Like,

1. - If the total SERVERS are [1 to 30] then the SERVER MAINTENANCE column should have the value 1
   - If the total SERVERS are [30 to 100] then the SERVER MAINTENANCE column should have the value 5
2. - If the total DATABASES are [1 to 10] then the DATABASE MAINTENANCE column should have the value 1
   - If the total DATABASES are [30 to 100] then the DATABASE MAINTENANCE column should have the value 10

Comment: Which DBMS? (PostgreSQL? MySQL? Oracle? SQL-Server?)

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag showing what database you're using, and an actual example of the output you'd like to have based on the data you posted. (A new block of data with the added columns of output and the column content.)

Answer (score 1):

usually, calculated columns are frowned upon as non-normalized.

here, you are articulating rules that can easily be entered as additional data into another table such as perhaps:

```
maintenance_limits
-------------------
type
min_count
max_count
result_value
```

then fill that in with your information:

```
DATABASE, 30, 100, 10
```

etc.

then you just need to write a simple JOIN query to get your 'calculated' result

Answer (score 0):

Don't store what can be calculated. Just use a query that will do this for you:

```
SELECT Environment, Servers, Databases,
    CASE
        WHEN Servers BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN 1
        WHEN Servers BETWEEN 31 AND 100 THEN 5
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Server Maintenance',
    CASE
        WHEN Databases BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 1
        WHEN Databases BETWEEN 30 AND 100 THEN 10
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Server Maintenance',
FROM XYZ
```

You may want to change `ELSE` to `NULL` depending on what you want to do with the data.